# Sorted multidimentional array displays values from one array at a time

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I have an array that consists of two merged arrays, which I have sorted using `array_multisort()`. The problem is that it seem to be displayind data from one array at a time, when I need it to display data depending on high-to-low values from two separate keys.

Right now it looks something like this...

```
[ Topic posted 10 minutes ago ]
[ Topic posted 20 minutes ago ]
[ Topic posted 30 minutes ago ]
[ Reply by user, 10 minutes ago ]
[ Reply by user,  20 minutes ago ]
[ Reply by user,  30 minutes ago ]
```

When in fact I need to display it in this order

```
[ Topic posted 10 minutes ago ]
[ Reply by user, 10 minutes ago ]
[ Topic posted 20 minutes ago ]
[ Reply by user, 20 minutes ago ]
[ Topic posted 30 minutes ago ]
[ Reply by user, 30 minutes ago ]
```

How can this be achieved?

Here is my PHP code:

```
$topics = $this->db->select("*")
    ->order_by("id", "desc")
    ->limit(10)
    ->get("forum_topics")
    ->result();

$replies = $this->db->select("*")
    ->order_by("id", "desc")
    ->limit(10)
    ->get("forum_topics_replies")
    ->result();

$merged = array_merge($topics, $replies);

$sort = array();
foreach($merged as $k => $v) {
    $sort['reply_date'][$k] = $v;
    $sort['topic_date_made'][$k] = $v;
}

array_multisort($sort['topic_date_made'], SORT_DESC, $sort['reply_date'], SORT_DESC, $merged);

return $merged;
```

**Edit:**
If using join queries, how can that be accomplished?

```
$topics = $this->db->select("*")
 ->from("forum_topics")
 ->limit($limit)
 ->join('forum_topics_replies', 'forum_topics.id = forum_topics_replies.id')
 ->order_by("forum_topics.id", "desc")
 ->order_by("forum_topics_replies.id", "desc")
 ->get()
 ->result();
```

**Edit 2:**
I need to be able to use the following fields:

topic table: `topic_name`, `id`, `parent`, `topic_date_made`

reply table: `parent`, `author` , `reply_date`, `id`

Comment: You need to use Join Query

Comment: i think an union could solve your problem as i posted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think an union statement could solve your problem - what about this ?

```
$query = $this->db->query('
    SELECT id, 1 as is_topic, parent, "" as author, topic_name, "Topic posted" AS praefix, topic_made_date as union_date FROM forum_topics
    UNION
    SELECT id, 0 as is_topic, parent, author, "" as topic_name, "Reply by user" AS praefix, reply_date as union_date FROM forum_topics_replies
    ORDER BY union_date DESC
    LIMIT 0,10
');
```

Comment: I'm not too sure on how to go about this - do I just return the result of this query?

Comment: `$query->result()` returns all your desired values - it works like `get()->result()` - if you execute this statement you'll see what you get ;)

Comment: I tried this and seem to be getting syntax error from MySQL when I do `SELECT * AS t1`, am I doing it wrong?

Comment: i think my exact query should do the job - you need a date and a title `topic posted` or `reply by user` - you dont need a `*` syntax here

Comment: Hm, yes, I see. I need to use more fields when I loop through the array later though - the dates are not enough. How would I go with achieving that?

Comment: the question is - which fields - in a union you've to make sure that you've the same amount fields in both select statements - (btw you didn't mention this in your question - so you should update this information)

Comment: I updated the question. Hopefully that'll make things clearer.

Comment: that couldn't be true - because you need also the `topic_date_made` field, but to be honest - if you need this fields for another different logic you should split this up in 2 queries, other wise this could become to messy here...

Comment: You are right - I thought that was obvious, but I added it to the post now. I did split it in two queries as seen in the post, but it's not ordering it correctly (which was the question to begin with)

Comment: you dont understand what i mean - it isnt totally clear why you need fields like parent or author - nevertheless i updated my answer (with a bit imagination you should be able to adapt those queries for your needs...)

Comment: Using your updated code, is there any way to determine whether a row is a topic or a reply? I need to show a different layout depending on whether it's a reply or a topic.

Comment: its quite simple  - just add another variable - i've added some to the code now `is_topic` - the value is 1 if it is one - otherwise it would be 0

Answer (score 1):

You can try adding the *`forum_topic_id`* or *`id`* whatever is the common table column/field between *`forum_topics`* and *`forum_topics_replies`* tables.

```
$sort = array();
foreach($merged as $k => $v) {
    $sort['id'][$k] = $v;// OR $sort['forum_topic_id'][$k] = $v;
    $sort['reply_date'][$k] = $v;
    $sort['topic_date_made'][$k] = $v;
}

array_multisort($sort['id'], SORT_DESC, $sort['topic_date_made'], SORT_DESC, $sort['reply_date'], SORT_DESC, $merged);
```

> UPDATE 1:

For array_multisort to work correctly the array keys of each array has to be identical. It looks like since the data is coming from different tables and you are just merging them it won't work.

So either you can try inner join, to join those two tables, which will generate exactly same number of array keys for $merged or you can manually massage both result arrays to get desired $merged array.

> UPDATE 2:

```
$topics = $this->db->select("forum_topics.id as topic_id, *")
 ->from("forum_topics")
 ->limit($limit)
 ->join('forum_topics_replies', 'forum_topics.id = forum_topics_replies.id')
 ->order_by("forum_topics.id", "desc")
 ->order_by("forum_topics_replies.id", "desc")
 ->get()
 ->result();

    $sort = array();
    foreach($topics as $k => $v) {
        $sort['topic_id'][$k] = $v;
        $sort['reply_date'][$k] = $v;
        $sort['topic_date_made'][$k] = $v;
    }

    array_multisort($sort['topic_id'], SORT_DESC, $sort['topic_date_made'], SORT_DESC, $sort['reply_date'], SORT_DESC, $topics);
```

Please try the above.

Comment: The ID field for both tables are called just `id`. Made no difference though.

Comment: Ok. I have changed the code to sort by 'id' instead of 'forum_topic_id'.

Comment: I changed it to sort by `id` the first time I tried it, that's what I meant. It made no difference to the order.

Comment: Oh ok. Can you please var_dump $merged may be just few rows to get sense of what data is returned.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I have updated my answer, I hope it helps

Comment: @P.Nick did the solution worked for you, if not please let me know.

Comment: Thanks for the input, I'm still working on getting your join method to work. If I get it working I'll accept the answer.

Comment: I updated the post with some code, I could not figure it out so far. Feel free to help!

Comment: @P.Nick Please try my update 2. If that does not work can you please paste the $topics result you are getting.

Comment: I tried something similar to that, but it doesn't work either. It seem to only print the topics when I do a foreach(), and because the `parent` fields are called the same thing for both tables it actually prints the reply parent instead of topic parent (and the same thing for `id`) var dump: https://pastebin.com/WQ75fb3H

Comment: I think since you didn't get the topic id may the sort didn't work. I have updated the query.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165322/discussion-between-kamal-soni-and-p-nick).